# No presenta los fonts awesome

Tags: html, nodejs, ejs, sailsjs

Estoy realizando un menu y necesito mostrar los fonts awesome pero no los presenta en la pagina, adjunto las versiones utilizadas:

node --version
v12.22.9

npm --version
6.14.15

sails --version
1.5.2

las dependencias:

"dependencies": {
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.1.1",
"@sailshq/connect-redis": "^3.2.1",
"@sailshq/lodash": "^3.10.3",
"@sailshq/socket.io-redis": "^5.2.0",
"async": "2.0.1",
"grunt": "1.0.1",
"nodemon": "^1.18.5",
"postgresql": "0.0.1",
"sails": "^1.0.2",
"sails-hook-flash": "^0.2.2",
"sails-hook-grunt": "^3.0.2",
"sails-hook-orm": "^2.0.0-16",
"sails-hook-sockets": "^1.4.0",
"sails-postgresql": "^4.0.0"
},

Como se ve en el navegador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Extracto del ejs utilizado para este fin:

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="btn btn-light mx-2" href="/mis-ordenes">Mis órdenes</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="btn btn-light mx-2" href="/lista-deseo"><i class="fas fa-list-ul"></i></a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="btn btn-light mx-2" href="/carro-de-compra"><i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i><span class="badge">
      <%=(session.carroCompra) ? session.carroCompra.length : 0%></span></a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="btn btn-light mx-2" href="/cerrar-sesion">Cerrar Sesión</a>
</li>
```

Alguien me puede apoyar indicando que más debo revisar.

Gracias

Comment: ¿Y ya has consultado la web de fontawesome a ver como se escriben realmente?  Porque diria que no es como lo has puesto, al menos para la versión 6.

Comment: Gracias, efectivamente ya funciono hay cambios en la versión 6. Ya actualice el código y qeudo así  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e280503399.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> en el layout que utilizo.